# How to set attribute value for textarea in JEditable?

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I use textarea element, and I need to set 'wrap' attribute as 'soft'. So, now I'm trying to edit library:

```
    textarea: {
        element : function(settings, original) {
            var textarea = $('<textarea />');
            if (settings.rows) {
                textarea.attr('rows', settings.rows);
            } else if (settings.height != "none") {
                textarea.height(settings.height);
            }
            if (settings.cols) {
                textarea.attr('cols', settings.cols);
            } else if (settings.width != "none") {
                textarea.width(settings.width);
            }
            textarea.attr('wrap', 'soft');
            $(this).append(textarea);
            return(textarea);
        }
    },
```

But it doesn't work. Please, tell me, how can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: Attribute `wrap="soft"` is default; you don't need to explicitely set it.

When you say "it doesn't work", what did you expect it to do and what did it do instead?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I expect that if I input a very long string that this string will be wrap to next one. Now I can input any string and it won't be wrap.